# Windows server 2012 on google cloud drops to command prompt using RDP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform

After installing Windows 2012 instance on google cloud, it drops to command prompt when ever I connect to it from RDP. It seems Explorer is not running on it. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it's running the Server Core version which doesn't have the GUI. You  can type `sconfig` to get a menu to configure the most common stuff.

I haven't used Google Cloud but on a regular Windows install if you are running the server core you can run `Add-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra` from powershell to install the GUI.

Comment: I noticed that I installed Server Core after posting the question. Hope this helps someone. Thanks.